# Unity Exception resolving type that is correctly mapped. Why?

Tags: wcf, interface, unity-container, resolve

I'm getting this error trying to implement the sample WCF Dependency Injection with Unity.

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "SampleServiceUsingUnity.ExampleService", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type,    ExampleServiceUsingUnity.IExampleManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:
Resolving SampleServiceUsingUnity.ExampleService,(none)
Resolving parameter "exampleManager" of constructor     SampleServiceUsingUnity.ExampleService(SampleServiceUsingUnity.IExampleManager exampleManager)
Resolving SampleServiceUsingUnity.IExampleManager,(none)
```

Problem is, I've tried to even explicitly map the types...and when I debug the code I go to the immediate window and look at the registrations.  See below:

```
**DependencyFactory.Container.Registrations.ToList()[2]**

{Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerRegistration}
buildKey: {Build Key[SampleServiceUsingUnity.IExampleRepository, null]}
LifetimeManager: {Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager}
LifetimeManagerType: {Name = "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager" FullName = "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager"}
MappedToType: {Name = "ExampleRepository" FullName = "SampleServiceUsingUnity.ExampleRepository"}
Name: null
RegisteredType: {Name = "IExampleRepository" FullName = "SampleServiceUsingUnity.IExampleRepository"}
```

So the mapping looks right, but when the service attempts to instantiate that interface using Resolve, I get the error.

The code examples are supplied at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323725.aspx

Comment: The exception is talking about `IExampleManager` while the registrations are about `IExampleRepository`. Any chance you are missing the mapping for the manager and instead supplied one for the repository?

Comment: I need to fix the error at the beginning of the post, and will do so shortly.  Apparently I pasted a similar exception from experimenting with different things.  The lines of code are below, and they WERE called when the service was instantiated...

DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterType<IExampleRepository,ExampleRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            DependencyFactory.Container.RegisterType(typeof(ExampleRepository));

Comment: Nope you got it right.  I screwed up.  I was so busy focusing on ExampleService and ExampleRepository I didn't even notice it was saying ExampleManager. (guess my eyes fuzzed over with the word Example).  I've just made a great argument for peer programming, haven't I?  Thanks!

Comment: Fancy posting your comment as an answer @SebastianWeber? Will allow for the question to be marked as answered. I would post what you said as an answer but wouldn't feel right doing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is talking about IExampleManager while the registrations are about IExampleRepository. Any chance you are missing the mapping for the manager and instead supplied one for the repository?